# Iterate through an array, looking for an item that has the same name as the parameter

Tags: c#

I have an array known as mItems. The array using a class called Item as a variable type. For this problem I need a method called GetItem to return an Item and take a string parameter. The method should iterate through the mItems array, looking for an Item that has the same name as the parameter. If it finds a match it should return that element of the mItems array. Otherwise return null.

I do not know how to tell if the array and Item share the same name or how to code this. As well as I think that I may possible be using the wrong variable type for my array. So far this is what I have as seen down below:

```
public Item[]mItems;

public string GetItem (string Item)
{
    if (mItems == Item)
        return Item;
    else
        return null;
}
```

The Item class looks like this:

```
public class Item
    {
        //Field
        string name;


        //constructor
        public Item(string name)
        {
            name = "";   
        }

        //Method
        public string GetName()
        {
            return name;
        }


        public string SetName()
        {
            return name;
        }
```

I keep getting errors like "Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Item[]' and 'string'

Comment: You can't compare string with array using a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in your example, the array `mItems` is empty. But lets say it actually wasn't empty, and look at the comparison line:

```
if (mItems == Item)
```

The left hand part is an `array`, containing instances of the class `Item`. The right hand side is of type `string`. You cannot compare different types like that (also, naming your `string` "Item", which is also the name of the class, is quite bad practice).

Depending on what the class `Item` contains, you might want something like this:

```
// The method takes a string input, but returns output of type 'Item'
public Item GetItem(string itemName)
{
    // You need to loop through all items
    foreach (var item in mItems)
    { 
        // Assuming that the class 'Item' has a property called
        // name, we can look for a match on that...
        if (item.Name == itemName)
            return Item;
    }

    // If we found no matches, return null
    return null;
}
```

You could also use LINQ, but the above solution is probably more beginner friendly...

Comment: With a little bit of tweaking I was able to get this to work. Thank you so much for putting me on the right path!

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide your Item class but I believe there is some property called `Name`. So the minimal definition of Item looks like this:

```
public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Your method should get wanted name as argument and return Item type hence it should be:

```
public Item GetItem(string name)
{
}
```

Now, as `mItems` is array, you should iterate it with some loop operator ([for](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/for) or [foreach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in)). With `for` it looks like this:

```
public Item GetItem(string name)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < mItems.Length; i++)
    {
        Item currentItem = mItems[i];
        if (currentItem.Name == name)
            return currentItem;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you cant compare between array and string, I think you want this one:

```
var mItem = new string[] { "sara", "jhon", "jack" };

public string GetItem (string item)
{

      foreach(var it in mItem)
      {
           if (it == item)
               return item;
           else
               return null;
       }
}
```